# ANDROID BADTOKENEXCEPTION: UNABLE TO ADD WINDOW, IS YOUR ACTIVITY RUNNING

Tags: android, xml, exception

I am trying to create a dialoguebox in my program.But an exception occurs that the activity has finished but i am trying to display a dialog with a context of the finished activity.But i am using only one activity at here.I have  4 button clicks inside my activity.Inside one of these button click i am giving the code for alert box.It shows that my application crashes

//here is the code

```
Allresidence.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if( Allresidence.isChecked())
                    {
                        Log.e("allresidence","checked");

                        selectButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                       Log.e("allresidence", "select button enabled");
                        //enable the button
                        selectButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v)  {
//                              the activity has finished but you are trying to display a dialog with a context of the finished activity
//                              if (Requestclass.!= null && !Requestclass.get().isFinishing()) {
                                Log.e(tag,"onclickworked");
                                AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                                        Requestclass.this).create();
                                Log.e(tag,"alertdialogobject created");
                        // Setting Dialog Title
                        alertDialog.setTitle("Alert Dialog");
                        Log.e(tag, "set title for alertDialog");
                        // Setting Dialog Message
                        alertDialog.setMessage("listview");
                        Log.e(tag, "dialogmessage setted");
                        // Setting Icon to Dialog
                        alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.gate_logo);
                        Log.e(tag, "icon setted");
 alertDialog.show();



//                              
//                          }
                            });
```

Inside this button click i am giving the code for creating dialogbox.I am tottally confused about what is happening.....the `alertDialog.show()` method wont executes in my program..

Below is my stacktrace

```
    03-24 11:04:51.588: V/InputMethodManager(1242): START INPUT: com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{416e6320 VFE..... RF....ID 0,0-320,391} ic=null tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@41a6eb08 controlFlags=#100
03-24 11:04:51.591: V/InputMethodManager(1242): Starting input: Bind result=InputBindResult{com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodSession$Stub$Proxy@41a16578 com.android.inputmethod.latin/.LatinIME #86}
03-24 11:04:51.667: I/SurfaceTextureClient(1242): [STC::queueBuffer] (this:0x51634fa8) fps:0.88, dur:1138.07, max:1138.07, min:1138.07
03-24 11:04:52.691: I/SurfaceTextureClient(1242): [STC::queueBuffer] (this:0x51634fa8) fps:0.98, dur:1024.43, max:1024.43, min:1024.43
03-24 11:04:52.715: V/Provider/Settings(1242):  from settings cache , name = sound_effects_enabled , value = 0
03-24 11:04:52.716: E/allresidence(1242): checked
03-24 11:04:52.718: E/allresidence(1242): select button enabled
03-24 11:04:52.881: E/aaaa(1242): nokeyboard
03-24 11:04:55.376: V/Provider/Settings(1242):  from settings cache , name = sound_effects_enabled , value = 0
03-24 11:04:55.377: E/Request class(1242): onclickworked
03-24 11:04:55.386: E/Request class(1242): alertdialogobject created
03-24 11:04:55.386: E/Request class(1242): set title for alertDialog
03-24 11:04:55.387: E/Request class(1242): dialogmessage setted
03-24 11:04:55.387: E/Request class(1242): icon setted
03-24 11:04:55.402: D/chenwei(1242): isHaveExternalSDCard=
03-24 11:04:55.404: D/chenwei(1242): isHaveExternalSDCard=
03-24 11:04:55.414: D/chenwei(1242): isHaveExternalSDCard=
03-24 11:04:55.436: D/chenwei(1242): isHaveExternalSDCard=
03-24 11:04:55.441: D/chenwei(1242): isHaveExternalSDCard=
03-24 11:04:55.444: D/chenwei(1242): isHaveExternalSDCard=
03-24 11:04:55.448: D/chenwei(1242): isHaveExternalSDCard=
03-24 11:04:55.451: D/chenwei(1242): isHaveExternalSDCard=
03-24 11:04:55.468: D/AndroidRuntime(1242): Shutting down VM
03-24 11:04:55.468: W/dalvikvm(1242): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x413869a8)
03-24 11:04:55.475: E/AndroidRuntime(1242): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-24 11:04:55.475: E/AndroidRuntime(1242): android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.app.LocalActivityManager$LocalActivityRecord@41a14ce8 is not valid; is your activity running?
03-24 11:04:55.475: E/AndroidRuntime(1242):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:646)
03-24 11:04:55.475: E/AndroidRuntime(1242):     at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:248)
03-24 11:04:55.475: E/AndroidRuntime(1242):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
03-24 11:04:55.475: E/AndroidRuntime(1242):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:281)
03-24 11:04:55.475: E/AndroidRuntime(1242):     at com.example.gate.Requestclass$4$1.onClick(Requestclass.java:296)
03-24 11:04:55.475: E/AndroidRuntime(1242):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4217)
03-24 11:04:55.475: E/AndroidRuntime(1242):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17502)
03-24 11:04:55.475: E/AndroidRuntime(1242):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:800)
03-24 11:04:55.475: E/AndroidRuntime(1242):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
03-24 11:04:55.475: E/AndroidRuntime(1242):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
03-24 11:04:55.475: E/AndroidRuntime(1242):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5371)
03-24 11:04:55.475: E/AndroidRuntime(1242):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-24 11:04:55.475: E/AndroidRuntime(1242):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
03-24 11:04:55.475: E/AndroidRuntime(1242):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
03-24 11:04:55.475: E/AndroidRuntime(1242):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
03-24 11:04:55.475: E/AndroidRuntime(1242):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Advance thanks......Any help will be highly appreciable....

Comment: is your activity finished then it's not posssible

Comment: remove this lineif (Requestclass.!= null && !Requestclass.get().isFinishing())

Comment: no my activity is not finished because i am using only one activity here,inside that activity

Comment: @karthikait is commented code

Comment: you should post your activity class too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the problem is like you are not passing correct context in alert dialog.
So to get correct context add below mentioned code in on click listener.

```
Context context = getParent();
this.mDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
```